# Responsive Div issue

Tags: css

One of the `ID="div"` isn't responsive. I've tried over my Android phone and even on my windows bluestack Emulator but it really doesn't move.

```
#div {
      background-color: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #dedede;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
      color: #888;
      display: block;
      margin: 8px 22px 8px 22px;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: Do you add `Responsive Meta tag` to your `<head>` section ?

Comment: Yes i do, <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

Comment: Giving a div a CSS ID of #div is kind of meta. It may help to give it an ID that quickly helps explain what its relationship is within the HTML & CSS. Can you please share a barebones example of the full html and CSS, to make it easier to help troubleshoot? It's possible something else might be interferring with the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's probably happening is that your parent element(s) has a fixed width which is forcing your `#div` element to also be the same width as your parent element.

width: 100% forces your element to be 100% width of the parent element.  So, for example, if your parent element(s) is another `<div>`, you need to also make sure that element also has a responsive width.

Here's a basic example:

```html
<!-- This will be 100% to the browser window -->
<div style="width: 100%">
  <div style="width: 100%">
    <!-- this div will be 100% of the window because the parent is 100% -->
  </div>
</div>

<!-- This will always be 1200px wide, not matter how wide the browser window is -->
<div style="width: 1200px">
  <div style="width: 100%">
    <!-- this div will be 1200px wide because the parent is 1200px -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried this and this one works! Thanks!